# Showing the right records

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, where-clause

I am making a sort of forum for myself to see how everything works. Its build in PHP (PDO) and now I got the problem. I can't figure out how I make sure when someone clicks on a record out of the `board` that it will only show the items with the `topic_id` that is set to that `board`

**This is the topic database**
[image]

**This is the boards database**
[image]

The code too show the board(s):
[image]

```
<section class="col-md-8 connectedSortable">
    <div class="box box-info">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading main-color-bg">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Boards</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
        <?php
           $boardss = $app->get_boards();
             foreach($boardss as $board){
               echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
               echo '<div class="well dash-box">';
               echo '<h3>'.$board['topic'].'</h3><br>'; 
               echo '<a href="https://####/boards/topics">'  .$board['omschrijving'].'</a>';
               echo '</div>';
               echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
   </div>
   </div>
</div><!-- /.box -->
</section><!-- right col -->
```

The functions I use:

```
public function get_boards(){
    $getBoards = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM boards ORDER BY id DESC");
    $boards = $this->database->resultset();

    return $boards;

}


public function get_topics(){
    $getTopic = $this->database->query("
    SELECT topics.*, klanten.foto, klanten.voornaam, klanten.achternaam FROM topics 
    LEFT JOIN klanten ON topics.klant_id=klanten.id
    ORDER BY id ASC");
    $topics = $this->database->resultset();

    return $topics;

}
```

Comment: Where is the `klanten` table data?

Comment: @D-Shih That isnt necessary to get this fixed?

Comment: Add parameter `$board_id` to `get_topics()`, then add a `WHERE clause` for the passed `$board_id` so that only topics of that board will be fetched.

Comment: Can you set that in a answer? @KarloKokkak

Answer (score 1):

When generating the link to the board page, you need to specify which board is actually called. Your current code looks like this:

```
echo '<a href="https://####/boards/topics">' . $board['omschrijving'] . '</a>
```

As you can see, the call itself, which is in the `href` attribute, does not contain any information. Instead, you should add the primary key of the board there:

```
echo '<a href="https://####/boards/topics?board=' . $board['id'] . '">'  . $board['omschrijving'].'</a>
```

If that is done, you can get the current board on the boards page via `$_GET`:

```
$currentBoard = $_GET['board'];
if (!is_numeric($currentBoard)) {
    die('Not a valid board id');
}
$currentBoard = (int)$currentBoard;
```

With that information, you can then can specify the topic for the board, by adding it to your query in `get_topics()` and adding the board is as parameter to the function. (`get_topics($currentBoard)`)

```
SELECT 
    topics.*, 
    klanten.foto, 
    klanten.voornaam, 
    klanten.achternaam 
FROM 
    topics 
    LEFT JOIN klanten ON topics.klant_id=klanten.id
WHERE
    topics.board_id = :board
ORDER BY id ASC
```

That statement uses the parameter `:board`, which you can replace in [a prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with the variable `$currentBoard`. I would highly encourage you to use prepared statments in that case.

Comment: @maybeiforgotmypassword Hey. I just merged my query into the query you already have in `get_topics()`. It uses prepared_statements for security reasons and you should get in touch with that technology. If you want to give it a fast try, just write `topics.board_id = '{$currentBoard}'` instead of using the `:board` placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter `$board_id` to `get_topics()`, then add a `WHERE` clause for the passed `$board_id`, so that only topics of that board will be fetched.

**Updated Function:**

```
public function get_topics($board_id){
    $getTopic = $this->database->query("
    SELECT topics.*, klanten.foto, klanten.voornaam, klanten.achternaam FROM topics 
    LEFT JOIN klanten ON topics.klant_id=klanten.id
    WHERE topics.board_id = '$board_id'
    ORDER BY id ASC");
    $topics = $this->database->resultset();
    return $topics;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you change my code so its more clear?